# ASP.NET Wizard Steps: Getting form data to next page?

Tags: asp.net

I can't figure out how to pass form data from a Wizard Steps Control to a new page. I posted [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461273/pass-hiddenfield-value-within-a-wizardsteps-control-to-next-site) some days ago, but the answer here didn't really help me because i can't even get the value from a TextBox on the new page.

I put tried to put this insted of the hiddenfield but `<asp:TextBox ID="amount" runat="server" Text="tester"></asp:TextBox>` but the `Request.Form["amount"]` is still just null.

How do i pass form data from a wizard steps control to a new page? Should this really be that hard?

Comment: Try putting your HiddenField outside of the Wizard and Make a FinishNavigationTemplate. In there you create a button with a PostBackUrl which will post the HiddenField to next page. It seems that the Wizard does not post to the next page when you use the FinishDestinationPageUrl attribute it just redirects to it. I have a code sample below if you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For information that we collect in a wizard usually translates into a business object, then we just pass that object around in a Session variable.  That way we have access to it on any page.

Comment: This was helpfull, but the reason i want to use HiddenField is that i have to pass the values to a script that my Online Payment company supplied to me. This script wants the total amount to be passed through as a hiddenfield, so sessions can't really help me. I guess?

Comment: So you're not the one consuming your code? In that case, your question is misleading, and its incredibly difficult to provide a good answer without your Online Payment Company's API at hand. Please re-phrase your question and describe *exactly* what you are trying to do.

Comment: Then on the new page, or the last step of the wizard, retrieve the session variable, and post the field(s) in your object to the page that contains the script.  I am still quite confused as to why you would need to do this, which API are you trying to use?  PayPal? Amazon?

Comment: Im using DIBS API. Its a danish company, dont know if they operates in other contries. But i will try your suggention.

Answer (score 1):

Session variable seems to be easier to work with:

Default.aspx markup:

```
    <asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="wizAwesome" FinishDestinationPageUrl="~/TestPage.aspx" OnFinishButtonClick="wizAwesome_FinishButtonClick">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="stepRock" runat="server" Title="Rock!">
                This is a wizard step.

                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenName" Value="Juliet" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>

    </asp:Wizard>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void wizAwesome_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Session["hiddenName"] = hiddenName.Value;
}
```

TestPage.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblName.Text = Session["hiddenName"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: but what do you do if you have to several fields that need to get sent over to the next page? I would hope you wouldnt create a Session variable for all of them

Comment: You'd just create a class which represents all the fields you want to pass over, then hold an instance of the class in a single session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your HiddenField needs to be located outside of the Wizard like below and you need to add a FinishNavigationTemplate which posts the data to your new page

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="wzd_Amount">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="step_Amount" runat="server">
            This is a wizard step.
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
    <FinishNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Finish" PostBackUrl="~/Labs/TestPage.aspx" />
    </FinishNavigationTemplate>
</asp:Wizard>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_Amount" Value="Test" />
```

On the other page you can just Request the data like so

```
lbl_Test.Text = Request["hdf_Amount"];
```